# Does par value include interest?

Tags: loans, bonds, bond-coupons

Is it only the principal amount, original cost of the bond at the end of maturity date or does it include the whole sum with the interest payments?

Comment: Better explore the concepts of dirty price and clean price.

Answer (score 1):

> Does par value include interest?

No - that is the amount of "principal" that you receive when the bond matures.  Interest that you receive from coupons on or before maturity is separate.

Comment: So the principal amount is the same thing as par value?

Comment: @Dan Essentially, yes, although "par value" is more commonly used for bonds, since it's often different that the amount paid for the bond, versus a loan where you give a set amount of money and get paid back over time..